# JSF/PrimeFaces client-side input manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, client-side

I have a JSF/PrimeFaces page in which a `<p:selectOneMenu>` has items populated from the values in a managed bean. Its items are actually sample queries described in simple statements to help users evaluate the system.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="sampleQueryInput">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.sampleQueries}" var="sampleQuery" itemLabel="#{sampleQuery.title}" itemValue="#{sampleQuery.query}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I want to insert the selected `sampleQuery.query` into another `<p:inputTextarea>` when user selects a sample query from the `<p:selectOneMenu>`. The text area holds the actual query which is to be sent and should be editable by the end user. I didn't find adequate information on the client-side API in PrimeFaces user guide, and I don't know whether I should use the PF client-side API or write my own javascript to handle that. How can I do this? I'm using PrimeFaces 3.3.1.

Comment: Use plain JavaScript to get the selected value on a textarea.

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid I had to do so if server-side manipulation was no option. Temporarily, I used <p:ajax> to trigger a method on the managed bean when the selected query changes and insert it into the textarea.

Comment: No need to go to the server when the resources are in the client side. You just need to check the HTML generated code and see how to get the selected value. In case this is a lot of work, then keep the ajax way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this in the `onchange` of your `p:selectOneMenu` (write a simple js function and call it)

```
var selectedVal = jQuery("[id$='sampleQueryInput']").find("select").val();
jQuery("#IdOfInputTextarea").text(selectedVal);//maybe it should be jQuery("#IdOfInputTextarea").val(selectedVal); , not sure
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :

`<p:selectOneMenu id="sampleQueryInput" onchange="callJavaScriptFunction()">`

in `callJavaScriptFunction` you can get the selected item by it's ID which is `sampleQueryInput` and put the value in `inputTextarea`.